# Limit alternative in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I want to print out only the max value. The problem is that I can't print that value it self. By using that max value, I need to determine which year should I print out. Everything works perfectly, what I need is to limit output only to one entry, by looking at taken maximum value. So I thought of this:

```
SELECT Years
FROM
(
    SELECT Book.Years,
        COUNT(Exempl.Taken) as taken
    FROM (Database.Exempl INNER JOIN Database.Book ON Exempl.Numb = Book.Numb)
    GROUP BY Book.Years
) as MyTable
WHERE (SELECT MAX(taken) FROM MyTable)
```

But I get an error. It doesn't understand `MyTable`. But I defined it as `MyTable`. What is the problem?

Comment: Aggregates must appear in the `HAVING` clause, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two immediate problems:

- The derived table `MyTable` (alias name for the subquery) is not visible in another subquery one level below. LATERAL in Postgres 9.3 would allow something of the kind, but the query is backwards anyway.
- The expression `MAX(taken)` does not evaluate to `boolean`, which would make it a valid `WHERE` clause but, again, the whole approach is incorrect.

Rewrite this. Probably the shortest form to get what (I think) you are after:

```
SELECT b.years, count(e.taken) AS ct_taken
FROM   database.book   b
JOIN   database.exempl e USING (numb)
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

1. Join table `book` to table `exempl` on the column `numb`. Since the columns have the same name, I simplified with `USING`. This is optional. Also using table aliases to simplify the syntax. Also optional.
2. Group by `book.years` and count the number rows where `exempl.taken` is `NOT NULL`. If `exempl.taken` is defined `NOT NULL` you can simplify to `count(*)`.
3. Order the result by this count (`ORDER BY 2`) and only return one row (`LIMIT 1`) with the maximum count. If there are multiple rows with the same maximum, the pick is arbitrary unless you add more `ORDER BY` items.

[Details in the manual about `SELECT`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)

Do you really have a schema called `database`? That's a most confusing design. Consider fixing that.

If there are multiple years for the biggest count, you get an arbitrary pick from those unless you add more `ORDER BY` items.

#### Without `LIMIT`

Use `row_number()` as [mentioned by a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22463954/939860), but over the count, not the base column:

```
SELECT years, ct_taken
FROM  (
   SELECT b.years, count(e.taken) AS ct_taken
          row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(e.taken) DESC) AS rn
   FROM   database.book   b
   JOIN   database.exempl e USING (numb)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 2 DESC
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

This works because you can have window functions over aggregate functions.

Comment: No, and as tile implies, I can not use Limit. If I could, I would have done it myself without any issues.

Comment: @user3178137: Can you elaborate why you can't use LIMIT? Either way, I added an alternative without LIMIT. Normally, you'd use the superior first solution.

Comment: Because I have a task in which I can not use Limit. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Years
FROM
(
  SELECT Book.Years,
         row_number() over (partition by book.years order by Exempl.Taken desc) as rn
  FROM Database.Exempl 
    JOIN Database.Book ON Exempl.Numb = Book.Numb
) as MyTable
WHERE rn = 1;
```